# Apply.Edit Function for Delete

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, json, delete

i have problem with my json of delete feature form Applyedit Jason on the arcgis server Json. Here my code.

```
delMaintData:  function(){
console.log('Bri');
            var maintTable = new FeatureLayer(this.dataSelect.get("value"));
            console.log('layer',maintTable);
            var deletesrecord = this.OBJECTID.get('value');
            console.log(deletesrecord);
            maintTable.applyEdits( null, null, [deletesrecord], function(deleteResults){
                //readTable(dijit.byId('assetId').get('value'));
                //dijit.byId('dialogAsset').hide();
                console.log(deleteResults);
            });

    },
```

i have [deletesrecord] to define the object id and i get the number          from console.log(deletesrecord); , and after the code in maintTable.applyEdits , there are log error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

Comment: try adding your FeatureLayer to a map before you call `applyEdits`.  http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/role/beta10_1/TklNMDc3OTgx